# How to get "href" from tag

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, nokogiri

I am trying to get "href" but can't.

I have this code:

```
<h3 class="list-item-hd">
    <a href="/music/news/dwight-yoakam-and-jack-black-to-produce-new-nashville-comedy-20151009">Dwight Yoakam and Jack Black to Produce New Nashville Comedy</a>
</h3>
```

How can I get?

```
/music/news/dwight-yoakam-and-jack-black-to-produce-new-nashville-comedy-20151009
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is using a CSS selector to grab all the anchor elements and print their `href` attributes:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOT
<html>
    <h3 class="list-item-hd">
       <a href="/music/news/dwight-yoakam-and-jack-black-to-produce-new-nashville-comedy-20151009">Dwight Yoakam and Jack Black to Produce New Nashville Comedy</a>
   </h3> 
</html>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.css('a').map { |link| p link['href'] }
# => "/music/news/dwight-yoakam-and-jack-black-to-produce-new-nashville-comedy-20151009"
```

You can achieve your goal by either using a CSS or XPath selector. To learn more about CSS and XPath selectors, I highly recommend you to take a look at the "[Official Nokogiri Documentation for Searching a XML/HTML Document.](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html)"